# How to create specific customer group to specific website in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, php

Is there any way to create groups which are specific to the website. Has anyone worked on this?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in Magento 2. You can create customer group, create customers specific to the website and then assign all those customers to the customer group you have created. In this way, you can manage the things.

Answer (score 2):

Customer groups cant be created for website/store specific.There is no option available in magento. I thing magento team didnt feel its requirement but you can create customer-group.  As customers can be create website and store specific, you can use it according to need.